# Allowing user to input both RGB and HEX values for bootstrap-colorpicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I see that you can set the value on the bootstrap-colorpicker for either using HEX or RGB. Our users need to be able to input what ever value they want. Is there a way to allow it to use both, or do I have to add some jquery to it like radio buttons or something that will change attribute setting for the control?

Library found here:http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-colorpicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to either do as you suggested using a radio button or checkbox to set whether it is HEX or RGB, or have a function tied to your input element that checks if it is RGB or HEX and converts it to either RGB or HEX based on what string option you are configuring the color picker with.

However, you may be able to get away with using one of their built in methods:

```
.setColor(value)
```

> The value is parsed and tries to do a guess on the format.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. I noticed that if they do have it set to one or the other, they can input the other type, and it just corrected it to the correct value of the other format. So if set to accept HEX, you can put an RGB into it, and it then will be resolved correctly upon losing focus of the control.